# How to proof that the square of the half-margin of maximum-margin SVM is equal to the summation of lagrange multipliers given by SVM dual?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lagrange-multipliers

Can be show that the square of the half-margin of maximum-margin SVM is equal to the summation of Lagrange multipliers given by SVM dual?

i.e,

Let
$
\rho = \dfrac{1}{w}\\
$

Show that:
$$
\dfrac{1}{\rho^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are Lagrange multipliers

Comment: I think this is only true for the separated case - is that what you had in mind?